# How do I connect Word to a different OneDrive for Business account?

Tags: user-accounts, active-directory, office365, onedrive, azure-activedirectory

**Background**

Our company is in the process of migrating AD domains and O365 tenants.  This is a phased migration with many moving parts.  We're now using our new accounts to access the O365 services, but still log into our computers using our old accounts.  The account on the new AD domain is a copy of the original, with the original account's SID showing in the new account's SID history.

When running Office apps locally, the account used to connect to OneDrive seems to be based on the current user's UPN, meaning that if I login as `oldDomain\user` I get connected to OneDrive on the old O365 tenant.

NB: We can't change the old account's UPN, since other services which have yet to be migrated still rely on this value for authentication.

**Question**

Is there some way to override this to tell Office which account to use when accessing OneDrive / prevent it from showing the old tenant & instead force it to use the new tenant?

Comment: FYI: The key seems to be down to this part of the registry: "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity".  By changing the LastSwitchedTime of a profile, the most recent becomes the default.  I've not yet looked into what's required by GPO to create a new identity in the registry, but sharing this info now should it help others.